Can you do a TDoA/PDoA localization between a Qorvo DWM1000 and an iPhone?
I would like to build a system for a school project where I need to get the distance and direction from an object to my phone inside a room, so UWB would be best suited for this case.
It’s my first time using this technology so everything isn’t clear at the moment, I think I got the basis but I have a question.
As I understood, TWR only gives you the distance between the two objects, if you want the direction you would need to use PDoA/TDoA (I understood the difference between the two, but I don't know which one would be best for my case) and thus, 2 antennas. I found the DWM1000 module to be suited for my project (we are on a cost constraint), but it only have 1 antenna, since I plan to use it with my phone (iPhone 15 Pro), I wondered if the phone had the 2 antennas, and if I could do the angle of attack computation from there instead of the module. If it isn’t possible, what solutions would you recommend?
